# How to use 'mainly'

Tags: sentence-construction

Where should 'mainly' stand in a sentence?

Which of the examples below is correct?

- I am **mainly** a quiet person.
- I am a quiet person **mainly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking (the simple rule), you should put the adverb (mainly) after the verb it modifies (am):

> I am mainly a quiet person.

Putting the adverb somewhere else is not necessarily wrong, but it may be misunderstood or not sound natural.
In your examples, the meaning of either phrase is the same.

Comment: You've already answered the question, but it would be great if you gave me some examples when the meaning changes. Thanks for the answer by the way.